# Why are my users being blocked?

Tags: joomla, user-account

A few members have reached out to me to say that their account has been blocked. I have gone into their accounts to "enable" their user status and change their password. However, the member is still getting the "block" notice and when I re-enter their account, their user status is flipped back to "blocked".

How to I enable these users that are continuing to be blocked?

Comment: What CMS are you using?

Comment: We're using Joomla!

Comment: This sounds like it could be an issue with Joomla rather than CiviCRM. You could try asking a question on https://joomla.stackexchange.com/. Also, if you are able to provide more information about your system that would help people to answer - e.g. which CiviCRM and/or Joomla extensions you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

A 'user' account is usually managed by the CMS. Their are integration tools that will set a user 'role' according to eg Member status or Groups, but that isn't what you are describing.

If you are using Drupal it could be that you had Drupal Rules that are designed to set a user record as Blocked based on some characteristic.

It may be possible to do similarly via CiviRules or an equivalent in WP.

Answer (score 1):

When you link up Joomla registration with a CiviCRM profile, you need to note if you've chosen the account to be immediately approved or to require admin or user approval. This information isn't communicated to CiviCRM, so even if you have approval turned on, the process will create a Civi contact using whatever profile you've chosen, and you won't be able to see the blocked status from within Civi.

In the case of people having their logins blocked, there are usually a few reasons:

1. You have user registration (In Joomla) set to have one level of approval, so all new accounts are blocked off the bat and only approved once either the user or admin clicks the link in the Joomla-generated email, depending on your settings.
2. The person has attempted a password reset through the built-in Joomla function and not completed it for some reason. When someone requests a password reset, Joomla blocks their user account until the process has been completed.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

"A few members have reached out to me to say that their account has been blocked. I have gone into their accounts to "enable" their user status and change their password."

Happy to help a fellow Joomlian Civi user!

CiviCrm generates "contacts". To give a contact rights to edit their own personal contact data you have to give them a Joomla "user account".

A user account is always member of at least one Joomla "user group". Users get assigned the rights that belong to the usergroup they are part of.

For instance: the right to see their own personal data and to change these. Members of a Joomla usergroup that functions as a CiviCrm admin group will have (lots of) rights beyond these two rights.

To set all possible CiviCrm rights for all Joomla user groups you have to login to the site management area (website.com/administrator) as a member in the Joomla superuser group.
After you login, you click on System/Global Configuration (left top-menu in admin area).
You will see 5 tabs with settings on top and left of these a column titled Component.
In this list you click on CiviCRM.

You see two tabs: Readme and Permissions.
In the Permissions tab you can set all rights for all user groups to dozens of CiviCRMs view and action rights.

This permits lots of fine detailed settings for lots of groups. The Joomla rights system is very flexible but takes some work to get familiar with.

I suspect that your problems could be the result of errors in these settings.

Hope this helps you along!